# How to join a WebRTC session with a Raspberry Pi 2 and Camera module?

Tags: linux, firefox, video, raspberry-pi, webcam

How does one get a working setup to join a WebRTC session (e.g. https://opentokrtc.com or for testing https://test.webrtc.org) with a Raspberry Pi 2, the official camera module (and a USB soundcard)?

How I tried it in several attempts so far:

- Boot Raspbian from microSD (also tried other distros)
- update all available packages
- set GPU/RAM split to somewhere around 192 - 256 MB for GPU
- install iceweasel
- visit one of the above sites, nothing happens (empty screen or black rectangle appears, no popups asking about sharing webcam/microphone)
- install all available [v4l2](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) packages
- reboot
- run iceweasel again
- it asks now for sharing webcam, microphone when visiting sites mentioned above, also shows the USB sound card (which works fine for playing audio)
- camera video pops up for about two seconds in random place on screen
- video vanishes
- same behaviour as before, failing to stream neither audio nor video
- running e.g. [raspistill](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/camera/raspicam/raspistill.md) to capture an image from the camera works just fine
- [installing chromium](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195) gives similar results, does also not work

After almost one full day of trying I didn't get anywhere. My goal was to use the Raspberry Pi as a video conferencing client which I could just leave running in our office, for people in my team doing home office. I read a few accounts of people managing WebRTC in their browsers on the Raspberry Pi, yet I failed.

Are there any known ways to get a Raspberry Pi to successfully join a video conference?

Answer (score 1):

Try [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org) with the Jitsi Meet plugin. It allows bidirectional audio&video on conference rooms over the web. You can specify room and username through the web interface. You do not necessarily need a browser on the Rpi2.

Comment: This is unfortunately not working. The interface greys out, as it should, after pressing start. But in the Jitsi room which I joined from another device is not joined, the Raspberry Pi does no show up.

Comment: follow the jitsi tutorial step by step you are probably missing something important. i have just tried, works perfectly.

Comment: Beginning to suspect it might be the camera I bought. With uv4l-uvc and a USB-cam it works. Weird though that raspistill and raspivid work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post but still, I have tried many things with this, the best and simplest solution for streaming from PiCamera in my opinion is:

1. Loading the uvl4 camera module driver "sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2", MY
2. Use Iceweasel or Firefox for WebRTC

If it`s not working, try to restart your Pi.